# Selenium behave debugging with vscode - python

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, automated-tests, python-behave

I have a desktop application made with electron that runs a react project. Already exist some test for my application and now I want put them in vscode using for debugging and implement them.

I am able to launch my exe, load all files (for example the breakpoints in the step files fires in the "Given" line) and debug the `enviroment.py` file. I'm also able (for test) in `before_all` function to interact with my app doing actions.

My problem is that as first fires `before_all` function and next `after_all` function, other files are ignored (features and steps) ending with a `0 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined`.

Here is my configuration in `launch.json` into `.vscode` folder:

```
{
    "name": "Python: all",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "behave",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "args": [
        "--no-capture",
        "--no-capture-stderr",
        "${workspaceFolder}/features/steps"
    ]
}
```

If can be useful, first the integration into vscode all works fine using the following command in cmd: `behave --no-capture > logs.txt`

As foler structure I have

```
root
-> features
-> -> steps
```

Thanks

**UPDATE 1: more info & code**
features/enviroment.py

```
#..imports..

apiPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
if apiPath not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(apiPath)
    
def before_all(context):
    #..code..
    context.my_app.open_app()
    sleep(2)
    
    context.queries_logger = logging.getLogger('MainThread')
    context.queries_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    context.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)-15s'
                                  ' %(levelname)-8s %(module)-15s:%(lineno)-8s %(message)s')
                                                                  
def before_feature(context, feature):
    #..code.. NEVER RUNS!
    
def after_all(context):
    context.my_app.close_app()
```

features/blabla.feature

```
Feature: Test of the parameters configuration of the XXX

  @XXX_XX @wip
  Scenario: User sets ...
    Given User add a XXXXX in the configuration file
      When  User enters in the ....
      Then  User checks that .....
```

features/steps/blabla.step

```
from time import sleep
from behave import *

@Given("User add a XXXXX in the configuration file")
def add_xxxxxxx(context):
    #NEVER RUNS!

@When("User enters .....")
def enter_xxxxxx(context):
    #NEVER RUNS!

@Then("User checks .......")
def check_xxxxx(context):
    #NEVER RUNS!
```

and I always get `0 features passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped`

Comment: Can you share the code that's able to reproduce the question?

Comment: @MollyWang I did the update 1, unfortunately I can't post the project's code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution.

*"${workspaceFolder}/features"* instead *"${workspaceFolder}/features/steps"*

```
{
    "name": "Python: all",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "behave",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "args": [
        "--no-capture",
        "--no-capture-stderr",
        "${workspaceFolder}/features"
    ]
}
```

and fixed the **os.path** directory that was edited in some script with the right one